# Excel Database data issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have a farily large database of around 2000 people, sheet1 has all of their names and relevant details. Sheet 2 has data pulled on from a site. I would like the data from sheet 2 to auto populate the cells in Sheet 1. Also if the person does not exist in sheet1 to highlight the data it couldnt do. I am so stuck on this.

```
Sub dup()
    Dim cell As Range, cella As Range, rng As Range, srng As Range
    Set rng2 = Sheets(2).Range("A2:E2000")
    Set rng3 = Sheets(3).Range("A2:E29000")
    For Each cell In rng2
        For Each cella In rng3
            If cella = cell Then
                cella.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                 '        cella.AddComment.Text Text:="duplicate value"
            End If
        Next cella
    Next cell
    Set rng2 = Sheets(2).Range("T2:Y2000")
    Set rng4 = Sheets(4).Range("A1:F2000")
    For Each cell In rng2
        For Each cella In rng4
            If cella = cell Then
                cella.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                 '        cella.AddComment.Text Text:="duplicate value"
            End If
        Next cella
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Its hard for me to show as it has a lot of columns not sure how on earth i can show you what im trying to do? :(

Try https://filetea.me/t1sfGPWECvdQqmgVDGtXL4oRQ

Comment: Excel is not a database.  It is a spreadsheet.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're trying to do, and what you mean by "autopopulate", since that workbook you've linked to is on a site that requires an email address to access, I'm sorry to inform you but most people will be skeptical of that (and many are skeptical to download files even from e.g., Google Docs, etc.).  Consider creating a (very) small set of example data and updating your question with those details...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, if you want to do it without vba, you could use the **LOOKUP** function in the sheet 1's auto populate column. It works like that:

> =LOOKUP(sheet1!A2, sheet2!table[a], sheet2!table[b])

This will find the value in the column "b" of the table in sheet2 based on the values of column "a". This will chose the value in the same row were column "a" matches the value in sheet1's A column. Let me know if I wasn't clear enough here.

Then you can use **Conditional Formatting** rules for the highlight you said. I suggest the **COUNTIF** function, that will return 0 if no matching value is found in the specified range.

> =COUNTIF(A2:A5,A4)

This, for example, cont values in A2:A5 that matches the values in A4.

Also, you will find the conditional formatting tools in the home tab, if you are using excel 2016.

See the link for more information:

[Information you may need](https://1drv.ms/t/s!Alh3Gl2bnj9c3HkZ8Z94yKKE6U7t)